# 50% border radius working on submit but not text input

Tags: css

I am trying to create a form with a text input and a submit button. I want the corners to be rounded. It's working correctly on the submit button but not on the text input:

```css
form {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
    form input[type="text"] {
        padding:5px 10px;
        border:1px solid #d7d7d7;
        border-right:none;
        border-top-left-radius: 50%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    }
    form input[type="submit"] {
        background:#000;
        border:1px solid #000;
        border-top-right-radius: 50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
        outline:none;
    }
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
 <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Search">
 <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

How can I make it so that the left corners of the text input are rounded off like they are on the submit button?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? It's working as expected, but it's not like you want to, try `em` or `px` values, as suggested in some answers

Comment: As you can see from the snippet you provided they obviously work only not in the way you want them i suggest you use pixels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `em` instead of `%`.

```css
form {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
    form input[type="text"] {
        padding:5px 10px;
        border:1px solid #d7d7d7;
        border-right:none;
        border-top-left-radius: 1em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    }
    form input[type="submit"] {
        background:#000;
        border:1px solid #000;
        border-top-right-radius: 1em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
        outline:none;
    }
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
 <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Search">
 <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

your 50% is calculated based on the width of the element. Since your submit button is very narrow and your text input is much wider, the border radius looks different. You will want to use some other absolute unit, such as px or em.

```css
form {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
    form input[type="text"] {
        padding:5px 10px;
        border:1px solid #d7d7d7;
        border-right:none;
        border-top-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    }
    form input[type="submit"] {
        background:#000;
        border:1px solid #000;
        border-top-right-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        outline:none;
    }
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
 <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Search">
 <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use percentages if you want a non-square element to have rounded corners. Use an absolute unit, like `px` or `em` instead:

```css
form {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
form input[type="text"] {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #d7d7d7;
    border-right:none;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
    background:#000;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
 <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Search">
 <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```